# Wrong time series detection

Tags: time-series, outliers, spark-mllib

I have a problem and I need help.

I have a time series and I need to know if the data is correct. Let me explain with an example. Suppose I have data generated by an atmospheric pressure sensor. The total data is 100 and of them 90 are equal to 0 and the rest are probable values around 1000 hPa.

In this case, it is most likely that due to some error, the sensor has recorded the values at 0. If a study of outliers were carried out, it is most likely that the correct values will be those that are detected as outliers.

For this example it is easy to know that if I am measuring atmospheric pressure the values of 0 are not correct. The problem is that I have several time series and each one represents data from different measurements.

I need to do an analysis that allows me to determine when I have erroneous values in a time series and that this analysis is independent of the measurement that is made.

I appreciate any ideas.

Note: I`m  using PySpark

Comment: It looks as if your sensor registering a plausible value is an uncommon event.

Answer (score 2):

This will be very hard without domain knowledge, and much easier with domain knowledge. I do not see how we can help you here.

For instance, the series you describe (lots of zeros, a few values around 1000) would be completely fine if it described rare but large orders or shipments between two nodes in a supply chain ("lumpy" demands). And conversely, data that might be wrong in this domain might be completely fine in a different context.

Comment: Thank you @Stephan Kolassa for showing interest in my question. I know it is difficult without having domain knowledge, but I have several domains such as ambient temperature, relative humidity, atmospheric pressure, CO2 level, precipitation volume, noise, water temperature, salinity, total dissolved solids, etc. I need to do an automatic analysis that allows me to determine if any of these time series have too many outliers to discard it. I had thought that calculating some measure of distribution could help me.
​

Comment: Would you not at least know which kind of time series you are dealing with? Then you could inject domain knowledge for each type separately, or at least collect large numbers of series of the same type and then analyze them together.

Comment: In reality, I can obtain information about which measurement corresponds to each time series. So, how could I use that information to achieve automated analysis of it?

Comment: I would suggest using this information to inform a rules-based approach. If you measure pressure, then a zero or a negative value is an error. For temperatures, such values are fine - unless you are measuring the temperature of a furnace, where you again assume that negative values do not make sense. And so forth. Or you could try some fully automatic approach, but that would be much more complicated. Perhaps someone will answer here and suggest something, but it is probably not the first approach I would try.

Comment: My hope is to get ideas from the answers and comments and your comments are helping me a lot. I hope someone else suggest something. I was thinking I might get something from a homogeneity analysis.